# Excel to email Date Format

Tags: excel, date, email, formula

I have the following formula to send data from a spreadsheet to an email.

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & A1 & "?subject=" & B3 &" Submit: " & D3 &"&body=" & H3, "Ready to Send")
```

However `Cell D3` is a date, and when it pull through to email, it's `43176` instead of the date. is there a way to modify this formula to keep it in the format I need rather than the serial?

I have tried DATE() with the usual format settings but still came out as 43176

Comment: Improve Formula format as code and highlighted some word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the TEXT() function to convert it to a string

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & A1 & "?subject=" & B3 &" Submit: " & Text(D3, "DD MMMM YYYY") &"&body=" & H3, "Ready to Send")
```

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-text-function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONCATENATE function along with TEXT() to maintain the date formatting for example:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2, "dd-mm-yy")," ", B2)
```

this would take the date in cell A2 in your specified date format and join with a space and then the value in B2.

For your spreadsheet layout, it would be:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("mailto:",A1,"?subject=",B3," Submit: ",TEXT(D3, "dd-mm-yy"),"&body=",H3), "Ready to Send")
```

Comment: Thank you. That sounds logical. Stuck in a boring meeting at the moment so I will try that in a bit..